# Calculating $\lim_{x\to0^+}x-\frac{1}{x^3}$

Tags: calculus, infinity

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}x-\frac{1}{x^3}$$

The answer is $-\infty$.

It's not very clear to me how was that concluded. You can't plug in the $0$ because you'd have $\frac{1}{0}$ which is indeterminate. But then again, I don't see much room for algebraic trickery to change the shape of the limit.

How can I proceed here?

Comment: Presumably you mean the right-handed limit, $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \cdots$.

Comment: Take x positive but small, like $10^{-n}$  what happens to the expression ?

Comment: When we calculate $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$, we always bear in mind that $x\neq a$ but that $x$ can get "very" close to $a$.

Comment: @Travis ah yes, you are right.

Comment: What level are you at, what tools are at your disposal? On some level it would be enough to just conclude $\lim_{x\to0^+}x-1/x^3 = -\infty$, but that would be too easy to ask for.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M < 0$; if $x > 0$ such that $x < \frac{1}{2}$ and $< \big( \frac{1 - 2^{-4}}{|M|} \big)^{1/3}$, then
$$
x - \frac{1}{x^{3}} < \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{x^{3}} = \frac{x^{3} - 2}{2x^{3}} < \frac{2^{-3}-2}{2x^{3}} = \frac{2^{-4} -1}{x^{3}} < M.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $y=\frac1x$. So as $x\to0^+, y\to\infty$. Thus our limit becomes 
$$\lim\limits_{y\to\infty}\frac1y-y^3=0-\infty=-\infty$$ 
We know that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}=\frac1x=[\text{Undefined}]$, but if we calculate the RHL, we will get $\infty$. (LHL is $-\infty$) 
And $(\infty)^3=\infty$